# How to generate a joined plot by adding a single point to a table listplot?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to generate a joined plot which consists of a series of points from a table along with a single extra point added by hand. However, when taking the following approach, I end up with the table listplot and the single point plotted separately and unjoined. Any suggestions (MWE and plot below)?

```
ListPlot[{Table[{a, a^2}, {a, 1, 4}], {{0, 1}}}, {Joined -> True}, 
 PlotMarkers -> \[FilledUpTriangle]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having two sperate lists you are effectively creating two sperate plots so they are not connected and are different colors.
You can joint the new point to the original list in a few different ways:

```
ListPlot[Join[{{0, 1}}, Table[{a, a^2}, {a, 1, 4}]], {Joined -> True},
  PlotMarkers -> \[FilledUpTriangle]]
```

(Joins two 2-dimensional lists.)

or

```
ListPlot[
 Prepend[Table[{a, a^2}, {a, 1, 4}], {0, 1}], {Joined -> True}, 
 PlotMarkers -> \[FilledUpTriangle]]
```

(Adds 1-dimensional element to the front of a 2-dimensional list)

[image]